# How do I check whether the result data set from an AJAX call has only 1 parent node?

Tags: jquery

Please refer to the if statement in the code:

```
function CreateProjectTree(sc)
{
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "../api/projects/SearchProjects",
        data: sc,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data)
        {
            if (data contains only 1 parent node)
            {
                //redirect page to X page
            }
            else
            {
                buildTree(data);
            }
        },
    });
}
```

The result of the call is an XML and I need to check whether it only has 1 parent node (regardless of the number of children).

How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `length` property of the jQuery object:

```
if ( $(data).length === 1 ) {
   // ...
}
```

Note that if the response's type of the request is XML, you should set the `dataType` property to `xml` and not `json`.

Comment: giving this a try now.